# Class member being an instance of another class

Tags: c++

I want to have a class member to be an instance of another class. But I get a warning "warning C4458: declaration of 'x' hides class member" and the code does not work.

`class Ca {
    int va = 5;
    public:
    Ca();
    int getVa(void);
};

int Ca::getVa(void) {
    return va;
};


class Cb {
    Ca x;
    public:
    Cb();
    int getCa(void);
};

Cb::Cb(void) {
    Ca x;   // instanciate Ca
}

int Cb::getCa(void) {
    return x.getVa();
}

int main()
{
   Cb cb;  // instanciate Cb
   int i = cb.getCa();
   cout << "va = " << i << endl; 
}`

I do not understand the warning, please could someone explain?

Comment: Just delete the line `Ca x;   // instanciate Ca`

Answer (score 8):

The warning is on this line:

```
Cb::Cb(void) {
    Ca x;   // <<== Here
}
```

The problem is that `Ca x` is a local variable unrelated to member variable `x`.

If all you need is to call the default constructor to initialize `x`, you don't have to do anything: C++ will do it for you automatically. If you would like to pass some parameters to `Ca`'s constructor, use initializer list:

```
Cb::Cb(int argForAsConstructor) : x(argForAsConstructor) {
    // Empty body
}
```

The construct after the colon lets you initialize members variables that do not have default constructors.

Answer (score 5):

You declare Ca x in the class Cb definition, then in the Cb constructor, you declare a new variable rather than using the one already defined.

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem here:

> ```
> Cb::Cb(void) {
>     Ca x;   // instanciate Ca
> }
> ```

Since `Ca x` is already defined as data member of class `Cb`, there is a *"conflict"* with the local variable you defined above inside the `Cb` constructor. The *"conflict"* is that the local variable `Ca x` *"hides"* the data member `Ca x`. While this code would compile, it is very error prone, and this situation is better avoided.

If your intent was to initialize the `Ca x` data member, you don't have to do anything in `Cb` default constructor: C++ does the initialization automatically. So you can just remove the `Ca x;` line in `Cb`'s constructor.

**EDIT** As @Jesper wrote in his comment, and I completely agree with him, since this is C++ and *not* C, consider eliminating the `void` from an empty parameter list.

Comment: @xaxxon: I elaborated on what I meant for "conflict".

Answer (score 1):

Your class `Cb` has a member variable named `x` defined here:

```
Ca x;
```

But then in your constructor, you declare a different variable named `x`:

```
Ca x;   // instanciate Ca
```

While this is technically fine, when you reference a variable in a class member function, when you refer to a member variable by name, *usually* you want to refer to the member variable, but in this case, since there's a local variable with the same name you wind up referring to the local variable.

This is a VERY common way to get difficult to identify errors and so it is a very good idea to heed the warning and not duplicate the name.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that the object declared locally in the constructor is immediately destroyed when the ctor ends, so that line of code does nothing and is completely pointless.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna to instanciate Class in the constructor, you can use like this:

```
class Ca {
    int va = 5;
    public:
    Ca();
    int getVa(void);
};

int Ca::getVa(void) {
    return va;
};


class Cb {
    std::unique_ptr<Ca> x;
    public:
    Cb();
    int getCa(void);
};

Cb::Cb(void) {
    x.reset(new Ca()); // Instanciate (Requires c++03 or newer)
}

int Cb::getCa(void) {
    return x->getVa();
}

int main()
{
   Cb cb;  // instanciate Cb
   int i = cb.getCa();
   cout << "va = " << i << endl; 
}
```